# PBR material : how to use a RMA file in Blender?

Tags: texturing, materials, pbr

I found this (free) [nice brick PBR](https://www.blender3darchitect.com/textures/free-pbr-brick-texture/) material :

[image]

I would like to use it in Blender. I had never heard of PBR before.
So when I unpack the zip, I get those files :

- Brick_Wall.sbsar
- Brick_Wall_D.tga
- Brick_Wall_H.tga
- Brick_Wall_N.tga
- Brick_Wall_RMA.tga

I've understood that sbar is a property format and is not supported by Blender.  So I have to build my own material using those textures.

[image]

I've read [this tutorial](https://blog.textures.com/how-to/2018/12/14/how-to-use-texturescom-materials-in-c4d-kkj9k) to learn how to setup it.

I added a **principled BSDF** node and linked it like that :

- Brick_Wall_D.tga > base color
- Brick_Wall_H.tga > metallic
- Brick_Wall_N.tga > (normal map) > normal

Is that correct ?

But then, I miss the roughness map.
I read [here](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/ChannelPacking) that

> RMA is a type of packed map which contains Roughness + Metallic +
>   Ambient occlusion, which are used with PBR (Physically Based
>   Rendering).

and [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/rma-textures-in-blender-internal-bge/688519/2) that you can extract channels in the node setup by using a "separate RGB" node.

Thus, what should I use and how should it setup that ?
Maybe I should use only the RMA file ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the height map for this.. the normal map will work fine (make sure to add the vector Normal Map and make the image texture non-color).

The RMA works like this.. add the RMA image texture and then add a "Separate RGB" node.  Each channel in the RMA is an input into your BSDF shader.  Most of the time it's this...

- Red = Ambient Occlusion (you can add this with a multiply on your Base Color if you want)
- Green = Roughness
- Blue = Metalic

I know this is an old question but maybe this will help others as this comes up early on Google for RMA and Blender.

Comment: just a quick one, RMA indicates also the order so 
R(R) => Roughness 
B(M)=> Metalness , G(A)=> AO.

Comment: For the other maps : (D)iffuse (= "base color" or "albedo"), (H)eight (=displace), (N)ormal

Comment: I didn't know that about "RMA" as a term.  Everything that comes out of Substance is as I descried above.. I'm not sure why.  There really should be a standard for that... I guess that's the "RMA" thing.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This slide from the Unreal Learning portal is visually clear what's going on with RMA packing.

As far as the order of RGB and its RMA correlation -- this video states it's something each studio / team does differently for their own needs and would be established early on in a project's Master Material.

This link here shows you exactly what the Blender workflow is of this concept

https://blenderartists.org/t/guide-texture-optimisation-channel-packing/1227744

And this slide shows an exact node group within Blender indicating that a single texture is being split by the Separate RGB node into the PBSDF shader's appropriate outputs.

[image]

Comment: This tells the OP what RMA files consist of, but it doesn't really provide them with a way to use that knowledge.  Consider adding a node group showing using a SeparateRGB node and other necessary nodes to attach the image texture to a (principled) shader.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.